# Matlab Simulation in Parallel

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I'm trying to speed up the excution of the genetic algorithm by trying to launch it in parallel.

But when I use the set_param function in my objective function Matlab complains about the non-existance of a Simulink block.
"Invalid Simulink object name : blocName"

But when I run the program without the parallel settings everything works fine. (Well, not that fine because it's really taking too long, but there is no error.)

Are there anything to add to the block name that I'm missing ?

Comment: A parallel computing worker is basically a new matlab instance, this instance needs to open the model as well.

Comment: I actually added load_system(FileName) in my objective function, and the simulation is running. But I don't know if it's the way to go.
I think I should have added it in the script just before running the GA.

Comment: Maybe running an initialization which opens the model on each worker is the fastest solution, but we don't know your code.